# ruby 1.9.2 uniq method not working against array of custom classes

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of custom classes.  I've defined <=> on them, and have tested to make sure that my custom definition behaves as it should. I assumed that I could then call [].uniq and have it filter out my duplicates, but that isn't happening. Is there another operator I need to overload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array#uniq` is based on equality, not on ordering, so your objects need to respond to `eql?`. Also, it uses hashing to speed up performance, so you need to implement `hash` as well.

Unfortunately, this contract isn't specified in [the documentation](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/core/Array%3auniq), but it usually *is* specified in pretty much every Ruby book or course.

Answer (score 1):

What I needed to implement, was .hash

Comment: I asked someone on the rails irc channel.